# How to apply classes instead of inline css style in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce

I'm using the the `advimage` `TinyMCE` plugin.

When I open the advanced image dialogue, and choose to justify an image to the left, it adds `style="float:left"` to the image tag.

However, I'm removing the `style` attribute from all tags when I sanitize the output.

Is there a way to have `TinyMCE` add classes, instead of inline css code, by default?

For example, instead of:

```
style="float:left"
```

I would like to have added:

```
class="float-left"
```

Comment: Excellent question! It is also relevant when wanting to use a strict `Content-Security-Policy` HTTP header, which does not include `'unsafe-inline'` as a source for styles. Any inline style attributes no longer work in that scenario.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Aside from using the `content_css` "styles" dropdown, which is usually loaded with lots of css classes you'd never use or present to a typical editor, there is also the Custom Formats option which gives very fine grain control over which classes are applied and what they can be applied to, and you can also override the default TinyMCE formats:

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration:formats

Example:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    formats : {
        alignleft : {selector : 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes : 'left'},
        aligncenter : {selector : 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes : 'center'},
        alignright : {selector : 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes : 'right'},
    }
});
```

Comment: This won't work with the advimage plugin, but it works for the other buttons, such as paragraph alignment.

Comment: +1 One thing to note with this approach is that the image *(or whichever element in question)* can not have the `mceNonEditable` class name applied to it. Due to the way this class name is magically removed from being shown to the user, it seems to mess up tinymce's ability of replacing class names. So instead of shifting from `class="mceNonEditable left"` to `class="mceNonEditable right"` you get `class="mceNonEditable left right"`. Just in case it helps anyone else out ther.

Answer (score 2):

When you are setting up tinymce using `tinyMCE.init()` there is in option in the parameters called `content_css`. You can use this to add a css file to tinymce.

You will also have to make sure that you have the `styleselect` option in the button list.

Here's an example setup: My apologies for the formatting, I'm copy pasting just now and I don't have time to start splitting up strings.

```
    tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode: "exact",
        elements: "textarea",
        theme: "advanced",
        plugins: "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,advlist,insertcode",
        convert_urls: false,
        width: "621",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1: "fullscreen,code,|,cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,undo,redo,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,blockquote,sub,sup,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,bullist,numlist,outdent,indent",
        theme_advanced_buttons2: "link,unlink,removeformat,cleanup,charmap,emotions,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,forecolor,backcolor,insertcode,template",
        theme_advanced_buttons3: "",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing: true,
        theme_advanced_resize_horizontal: false,
        tab_focus: ":prev,:next",
        extended_valid_elements: "textarea[cols|rows|disabled|name|readonly|class]",

        // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
        content_css: "/CSS/main.css"

    });
```

Comment: This won't affect TinyMCE adding inline styles using the align left|right|center buttons, or any of the other features that add inline styles, like font-size, font-family, etc.

Comment: @Madmartigan: No - It'll just give you the ability to add classes from a styles drop-down in your tool-bar. It will also apply any styles to content within your html. btw Cool handle, love Willow!

Comment: @Madmartigan exactly, I wonder if it is possible with TinyMCE. I would think it is a common concern...

Comment: @Deb, Madmartigan:  I might be missing something but any inline style you add using alignment buttons, font-family etc will always overwrite the external css. with or without tinymce. Of course anything like headers or p tags will conform to the style set in your style sheet unless they are doctored too.

Comment: I'm removing the style attribute from any user input, as I mentioned in the question